# Configure text logs for Amazon Lex results in "There are no log streams"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am trying to follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/conversation-logs-configure.html) guide to configure conversation logs.

Here's what I've tried:

- Navigated to CloudWatch and created a new LogGroup
- Navigated to my bot and published it so I now have an alias Latest:1
- Clicked the gear next to the latest alias in conversation logs and
- Selected text logs
- Selected the log group I created
- Selected Admin (fullaccess) for permissions
- Asked a test question in the test bot window and on the web app version I have running on cloud front

The problem is that no logs ever show up in my CloudWatch group: "There are no log streams."

Any idea what might be going on here?